# Redis Overiding remote host in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure-devops, redis

I am connecting to a remote Redis using the following code. The problem connecting because it does not accept the giving IP instead points to localhost.

```
const redisURL = "redis://20.213.158.211:6379"  // random remote IP address
const client = redis.createClient({redisURL});

client.on('connect', function(){
  client.select(5);
  console.log('Connected to Redis');
});

client.on("error", (err) => console.log("Redis Client Error", err));
 client.connect();
```

It throws the following error

```
Redis Client Error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 6379
}
```

The problem is it still trying to connect to `127.0.0.1`(localhost) instead of the giving IP address above.

Comment: For anyone also having this problem. After so much research, I discover there is an open issue with the npm Redis library that has not been resolved and it is responsible for the error above. My solution was to roll back to version 3.0.2 and it works

Comment: Hi, if you find the solution/workaround, could you please post an answer and [mark it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0iMP.png), this will be helpful for others who encounter the similar issue.

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT I am doing that now.

Comment: My answer was not accepted so i amdroping it here as a comment.   Rolled back to version 3.0.2, therefter connection example below  ``` // const client = redis.createClient({
//     port: process.env.REDIS_PORT ',
//     host: process.env.REDIS_HOST ',
//    password:'your assword'
//   }); ```

Comment: You can [post an answer here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVqhi.png), and [mark it as the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0iMP.png). This will help others find the solution easier. Thanks for your contribution!

Comment: In general, even a temporary workaround can be marked as an answer. In this way, people can clearly know that there is a solution/workaround for this problem when searching, and what to do next when encountering this problem. You can also reaccept the better one if a better answer comes up after you post and accept the another answer.